# Synonyms of "to be poor/bad/deficient at doing something"

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for synonym expressions of:

> are **bad at** doing something

> is **poor at** doing something

> are **deficient at** doing something

Ideally the synonym expressions should be formal (I feel that "bad at" is a bit informal), shorter, and avoid using the verb "to be", but I am open to any proposals. Thanks

Comment: "Sucks at" is best, but not what you requested

Answer (score 2):

You may say "He is incompetent." or "unskilled".

You may avoid "be" verbs by rephrasing with an adverb:  He does something badly", or "incompetently"

These are all quite strong.  You can be a little softer by negating the verb with a positive adverb:  "He doesn't do something well".

You can describe his skills, or skillset as "weak".

> John is an incompetent lawyer.  His preparation is weak.  He argues cases in court badly. He doesn't negotiate with clients well either.

Comment: I like the suggestion of replacing adjectives conditioning the doer with adverbs conditioning the verb. Saying she does something 'badly' or 'poorly' works if you want to avoid the verb 'to be' for some reason!

Answer (score 2):

"poor at" (or "weak at/in") is more formal than "bad at".

Personally, I don't like "deficient at"; I think in most cases "deficient in [some noun phrase (rather than a gerund)]" works rather better; e.g. "... deficient in English conversation" rather than "... deficient at speaking English", Although "... poor at English" might be even better, avoiding 'deficient' altogether!

You could also use a negative of an adjective with the opposite meaning if you want to soften your statement a bit: "... are not good at ...", " ... is not well-trained/proficient/ in ...".

Or that old faithful "... can't do x very well", or maybe a more formal equivalent: "... is not best equipped to do x", "... is ill-suited to [some task]"

Answer (score 1):

While this may lean on too harsh, the word *inept* might be suitable.